# No suitable method to override

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I am using DayPilot to create a calendar in the monthly view.

So following this [tutorial](https://mvc.daypilot.org/monthly-calendar-and-sql-server-tutorial/), I have this:

```
public class Dpm : DayPilotMonth
{
    MyCalendarEntities db = new MyCalendarEntities();

    protected override void OnInit(InitArgs e) // this is where I receive the error
    {
        Update();
    }

    protected override void OnFinish()
    {
        // only load the data if an update was requested by an Update() call
        if (UpdateType == CallBackUpdateType.None)
        {
            return;
        }

        Events = db.Events.ToList();

        DataStartField = "StartDate";
        DataEndField = "EndDate";
        DataTextField = "Event1";
        DataIdField = "ID";

    }
}
```

I am only receiving the error on the `OnInit` method, but not on the `OnFinish` method even though in the base class they are pretty much declared the same:

**Base Class:**

```
public class DayPilotMonth
{
    protected DayPilotMonth();


    public string BackColor { get; set; }

    public string HeaderBackColor { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; }

    public string NonBusinessBackColor { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek ResolvedWeekStart { get; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public CallBackUpdateType UpdateType { get; }
    public DateTime VisibleEnd { get; }
    public DateTime VisibleStart { get; }

    public WeekStarts WeekStarts { get; set; }
    protected Controller Controller { get; }

    protected string DataEndField { get; set; }

    protected string DataIdField { get; set; }

    protected string DataStartField { get; set; }

    protected string DataTextField { get; set; }
    protected IEnumerable Events { get; set; }

    public ActionResult CallBack(Controller c);

    protected virtual void OnBeforeEventRender(BeforeEventRenderArgs e);
    protected virtual void OnCommand(CommandArgs e);
    protected virtual void OnEventClick(EventClickArgs e);
    protected virtual void OnEventMove(EventMoveArgs e);
    protected virtual void OnEventResize(EventResizeArgs e);
    protected virtual void OnFinish();
    protected virtual void OnInit(InitArgs e);

    protected virtual void OnPrepare();
    protected virtual void OnTimeRangeSelected(TimeRangeSelectedArgs e);

    protected void Redirect(string url);
    protected void Update();
    protected void Update(object data);
    protected void Update(CallBackUpdateType type);
    protected void Update(object data, CallBackUpdateType type);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that there are two classes with name `InitArgs` ?

Comment: As it turns out there are! I never thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: check InitArgs parameter namespace, Nothing else comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this using:

```
using DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Events.Month;
```

Or even better:

```
protected override void OnInit(DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Events.Month.InitArgs e) {..
```